# How can I send a message to a Java program with a server in Objective C?

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, sockets

I am trying to create a server in Objective C to make a connection between a program which is written in Java and an application written in Objective C. I decided to use the socket method with the input and output streams. I don't understand why the communication between the Java program and my Objective C server isn't working. They seems to send message but I think they don't understand each other.
I used the tutorial from this website :

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/ReadingInputStreams.html

So please can you just look at my code and tell me if you see something wrong ? It will be really helpful. Thanks very much.

```
- (id)initWithPortNumber:(int)pn delegate:(id)dl{


        NSLog(@"Start connection");

        socketPort = [[NSSocketPort alloc] initWithTCPPort:pn];
        int fd = [socketPort socket];
        fileHandle = [[NSFileHandle alloc] initWithFileDescriptor:fd closeOnDealloc:YES];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(newConnection:)
                                                            name:NSFileHandleConnectionAcceptedNotification
                                                                object:fileHandle];

        [fileHandle acceptConnectionInBackgroundAndNotify];

        NSLog(@"Socket cree");


        return self;
}

- (void) newConnection:(NSString *)path{

NSLog(@"Connection accepted");

CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;

CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"localhost", 56103, &readStream, &writeStream);

inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

[inputStream retain];
[outputStream retain];

[inputStream setDelegate:self];
[outputStream setDelegate:self];

[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode ];

[inputStream open];
[outputStream open];    
}

- (void)stream:(NSStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode {
NSMutableArray *_data;
NSLog(@"stream:handleEvent: is invoked...");

switch(eventCode) {


    case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
        [stream close];
        [stream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        NSLog(@"Problem with Server");
        break;

    case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable: ;
        NSLog(@"Read Input NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable");

        if(!_data) {
            _data = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
        }
        uint8_t buf[1024];
        unsigned int len = 0;
        len = [(NSInputStream *)stream read:buf maxLength:1024];
        if(len) {
            [_data appendBytes:(const void *)buf length:len];
            [bytesRead setIntValue:[bytesRead intValue]+len];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"no buffer!");
        }
        break;

    case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
        NSLog(@"NSStreamEventErrorOccurred.");
        NSError* error = [stream streamError];

        NSString* errorMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (Code = %d)",
                                  [error localizedDescription],
                                  [error code]];
        NSLog(@"%@",errorMessage);
        break;

    case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:;

        NSLog(@"Write output NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable");
        NSString * string =@"OK\n";
        NSData * data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];

        break;

    case NSStreamEventNone:
        [stream close];
        [stream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        NSLog(@"server problem");
        break;

    case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
        NSLog(@"%@ Stream Open",stream);

        break;
    }
}
```

And a last thing : when I run the server and the Java program I can read this in the output. It can maybe help you.

```
2014-08-22 09:57:59.375 CocoaSpeech[791:303] stream:handleEvent: is invoked...


2014-08-22 09:57:59.376 CocoaSpeech[791:303] <__NSCFInputStream: 0x60800009eb90> Stream Open

2014-08-22 09:57:59.376 CocoaSpeech[791:303] stream:handleEvent: is invoked...
2014-08-22 09:57:59.376 CocoaSpeech[791:303] <__NSCFOutputStream: 0x60800009edc0> Stream Open
2014-08-22 09:57:59.376 CocoaSpeech[791:303] stream:handleEvent: is invoked...
2014-08-22 09:57:59.376 CocoaSpeech[791:303] Write output NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable
2014-08-22 09:57:59.377 CocoaSpeech[791:303] stream:handleEvent: is invoked...
2014-08-22 09:57:59.377 CocoaSpeech[791:303] Write output NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable
```

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to your problem?